# ORDER BY 2 values that might be NULL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I want to order by two dates, **startdate** and **enddate**, either one could be null.

1. I want to order them first by start date, then by end date.
2. if end date is null I don't want to order by that at all.
3. All start dates with null end dates come before all start dates with end dates.
4. If start date is null, I want those entries to be last in the list. (Null start dates will have null end dates associated with them.)

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Just for clarification, points 2 and 3 seem somewhat contradictory.  If enddates are null you can't just 'not sort by them'- these rows need to go somewhere (unless you want them filtered out, which should be done in the WHERE clause).  Point 3 seems to indicate that you want them sorted to be last...

Comment: My database is MySQL
Also yes point 2 and 3 do seem that way, but I guess what I was looking for was a way to handle the null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ORDER BY clause should do it:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN startdate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  startdate,
  CASE WHEN enddate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  enddate
```

Depending on your DBMS there may be simpler ways of doing this, although not necessarily portable.

Answer (score 2):

If your database is Oracle, then you can write:

```
SELECT startdate, enddate
FROM yourtable
ORDER by startdate NULLS LAST, enddate NULLS FIRST;
```

Comment: @TinaBerger: If I'm not mistaken, MySQL doesn't support NULL LAST/FIRST. So you'll have to go with PinnyM's solution.